# Confusion regarding order of the parameter in constructor method

Tags: java, constructor

```java
public class Wall {
    private double width;
    private double height;

    public Wall() {}

    public Wall(double width, double height) {
        this.setHeight(height); // using method to set the required fields. //This method is called with unexpected behavior.
        this.setWidth(width);  // This is not getting called?

    }

    public double getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(double width) {
        if (width <= 0) {
            this.width = 0;
            System.out.println("INVALID VALUE - The width of the wall is updated to :" + 0.0);

        } else {
            this.width = width;
            System.out.println("The width of the wall is updated to :" + width);
        }
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(double height) {
        if (height <= 0) {
            this.height = 0;
            System.out.println("INVALID VALUE - The width of the wall is updated to :" + 0.0);
        } else {
            this.height = height;
            System.out.println("The height of the wall is updated to :" + height);
        }
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return width * height;
    }

}
//OUTPUT
The width of the wall is updated to :10.0 \\ Expected
INVALID VALUE - The width of the wall is updated to :0.0 \\ not expected

//OUTPUT when parameter order in constructor is reversed
INVALID VALUE - The width of the wall is updated to :0.0 \\expected
The height of the wall is updated to :10.0 \\expected
```

The goal was to avoid code repetition and I chose to use the setter method in constructor. Also assuming since I am using methods and providing appropriate parameters, the order of the parameter should not matter.

I am not sure if it is supposed to work that way. I see that the method is being called with unexpected behavior.

Few doubts I have regarding the above

- Not all methods are getting called in the constructor
- Can these setter methods be static and perform operation on the object being created?
- What would be the right way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: message in setHeight method if condition is wrong. It is referring to width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see that the method is being called with unexpected behavior.

`setHeight()` actually performs as expected but it is not implemented as you'd expect it. You probably copied it from `setWidth()` and forgot to change the message so it would print "INVALID VALUE - The **width** of the wall is updated to : xxx".

> the order of the parameter should not matter

The order in which you *define* the parameters doesn't matter from a technical point of view (unless you have a vargs parameter which needs to be last). However the order of definition leads to the requirement of providing values in the same order when calling the constructor.

Example: `Wall(double width, double height)` defines the 1st parameter is width and the 2nd is height.

Assume the following:

```
double width = 5.0;
double height = 7.0;

Wall w = new Wall(height, width);
```

Here, the names of the parameters don't matter but order does, i.e. `w` now has a width of 7 and a height of 5 even though the parameters were named otherwise.

What shouldn't matter in most cases is the order in which you call the setters inside the constructor - as long as they're independent.
This means the following 2 should be equivalent:

```
public Wall(double width, double height) {
    this.setHeight(height); 
    this.setWidth(width);
}

public Wall(double width, double height) {
    this.setWidth(width);
    this.setHeight(height); 
}
```

When would order matter? If setters were depending on it - not a good style though. Suppose `setHeight()` would check that `height > width`. Now if you'd not call `setWidth()` first `setHeight()` might behave differently. However, I repeat: *this it not good style and should be avoided!*

> Not all methods are getting called in the constructor

Not sure what you're referring to but constructors don't have to call any method nor do you have to call all the setters there. It really depends on what you want to achieve.

Use constructors for mandatory parameters and setters for mutable ones (and potentially optional). Mutable parameters are those that could be changed after constructing an object, immutable ones should not change - there shouldn't be any setter for those (ideally declare those `final` and the compiler will complain about setters for those).

Summary:

- mandatory + immutable parameters: use constructor only
- mandatory + mutable parameters: use constructor which can call setters
- optional + mutable parameters: use setters
- optional + immutable parameters: use constructor only, potentially via constructor overloads

> Can these setter methods be static and perform operation on the object being created?

No, setters should never be static because you'd need to pass the object anyway and thus it's cleaner to just have the setters there.

However, a constructor can call static methods if necessary. Suppose you have a condition to check that `width < height` which you'd want to call in the constructor and the setters. This could then look like this (simplified and lacking a lot of best practices to keep things simple):

```
 //example of constructor calling the static method
 public Wall(double width, double height) {
    //check the condition on the input parameters
    if( !checkCondition(width, height) ) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("width >= height");
    }      

    this.setHeight(height);
    this.setWidth(width);
 }

 //example of setter calling the static method
 public void setWidth(double width) {
   //only set if the condition is met
   if(checkCondition(width, this.height) {
     //rest of your code
   } else {
     System.err.println("width would be < height, thus not updating width");
   }
 }

 private static boolean checkCondition(double width, double height) {
   return width < height;
 }
```